# What's the meaning of *? in regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I've run across some code several times that has a regular expression with:

```
\((\X*?)\)
```

to match everything in parenthesis. If * is repeat 0 or more times and ? is zero or once, it seems extraneous to have both. Is *? equivalent to * or does it have some special meaning with both combined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`?` after `+` or `*` makes that operator *non-greedy*, that is, it will try to match a *minimum* number of times instead of a *maximum* number of times.

For example, matching `{hi}{there}` with `{(.*)}` matches the group `hi}{there` which may be undesirable. Using the non-greedy `{(.*?)}` gives the matches `hi` and `there` as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I've had to get more and for familiar with regex as a second language, but this was a first.

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere! Glad I could help.